# TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing What is wrong?

Tags: python, django

I got an error,TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing.
I wrote codes,

```
        user = Data()
        passwd = request.data['password']

        md5 = hashlib.md5()
        md5.update(passwd)

        user.password = md5.hexdigest()
        print(user.password)

        user.save()
```

Traceback　says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 95, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 494, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 454, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 491, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/project/app/views.py", line 27, in create
    md5.update(passwd)
```

I added #coding:utf-8 to top of the code,but same error happens.What is wrong in my codes?How should I fix this?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585307/how-to-correct-typeerror-unicode-objects-must-be-encoded-before-hashing, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27519306/hashlib-md5-typeerror-unicode-objects-must-be-encoded-before-hashing. Note that `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` defines the encoding of your source file, and is [redundant in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14083111/should-i-use-encoding-declaration-in-python3), since it defaults to utf-8.

Comment: It could be a bad idea to use md5 as password hash algorithm. Check this question for details: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure

Answer (score 3):

The error tells you what you need to do: encode the password to a bytestring.

```
md5.update(passwd.encode('utf-8'))
```

Note though you probably shouldn't be doing this at all; if you want to use a user's password, use the `set_password()` method of the User model.

(And please don't randomly add encoding declarations to your script; that only effects literal characters in the file.)